# How to use loop for pushing data into firebase using php?

Tags: java, php, swing, loops

Below code is for pushing values into firebase using swing which i have done, but now i have to convert it into php but while i am converting i have firebase sdk for php but i dont understand how to use loop in that sdk..?

```
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
        DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child(appName);
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); ++i) {
            Map<String, Object> userUpdates = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            String phone = myList.get(i);
            System.out.println("mobile" + phone);
            userUpdates.put("phoneNumber", phone);
            userUpdates.put("sentMessage", false);
            usersRef.child("contacts").child(mobile).push().updateChildren(userUpdates);

        }
```

my php implementation is below..

```
      for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
      $arr = array("$mobile" =>array("phoneNumber"=>$myList($i), "sentMessage"=>false));  
      $data_string = json_encode($arr);
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
      );
      echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
      }
```

is my php implementation above is correct. if not what is wrong here?

Comment: It would be helpful to SO folks if you post your PHP implementation.